# Is there a function for closing app on mouse or keyboard movement in PyQT5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want my app to close when mouse or keyboard movement is detected, it does not detect anything, only when I close the app

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
      QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
      self.setupUi(self)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key():
           self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = MainWindow()
   w.showMaximized()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 1. look up how to detect mouse or keyboard events, 2. use that to trigger your app to close

Comment: I tried, only when I close it identifies

Comment: You cannot use long-lasting loops and blocking functions in UI threads. Do you want to close the app when its window(s) receive those events, or when they happen when other programs have focus?

Comment: @musicamante I want my app to close when keyboard or mouse cliked is detected

Comment: @Fernando Sorry, but that answer is insufficient. The mouse can be moved and keys could be pressed at *any* given time, and only the *active* program alone or the OS could get such events. If your program window(s) are not currently focused, the user might move the mouse or press a key. Do you want to get those events too, or do you want to get them *only* when a window of *your* program has focus (is the "active" window)? Those situations are ***not*** the same, and if you don't know the difference I strongly advise you to do more research on how mouse and keyboard interaction work in OSs.

Comment: @musicamante Only when a window of my program has focus is the "active" window (I'm using qt-designer)

Comment: @Fernando then just override the [`mouseMoveEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent) (and ensure that the widget has [`setMouseTracking(True)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop)) and [`keyPressEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent).

Comment: @musicamante The keyboard worked but the mouse didn't. Would it be possible to close the window just if I click on the QStackedWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input events are not propagated to the parent if a child handles them.

If a widget accepts keyboard events, they will not be received by its parent(s).

A widget receives mouse move events only if it *grabs* the mouse (normally, after clicking on *that* widget) or if it has the `mouseTracking` property enabled *and* the mouse is actually over the widget, but *not* if the mouse is over a *child* widget (or a widget that partially covers it).

Since your top level widget has children, those events might never be received, as those children will handle and/or accept them.

The solution is to install an event filter on the global application, and check for both `MouseMove` and `KeyPress` events, then eventually quit the application, being careful to do that with a delayed timer, as the application will still need to finish processing its event queue:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        QApplication.instance().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() in (event.MouseMove, event.KeyPress):
            QTimer.singleShot(0, QApplication.quit)
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```

Comment: Does it work with mouse movement and to close the window only if I click on the QStackedWidget?

Comment: If you want to close on mouse click, then use `event.MouseButtonPress` instead of `event.MouseMove`.

Comment: And to close if you click on the QstackedWidget, not anywhere on the window

Comment: What stacked widget? We cannot provide valid answers if you keep changing idea and don't provide a [mre], as right now we don't know the ui structure since you didn't share the contents of that file.